# Data not directly refreshed with Angular Observable Data Services

Tags: angular, observable

I implemented the Angular Observable Data Services following this [tutorial](https://coryrylan.com/blog/angular-observable-data-services) in my project. Actually, I am facing a problem with the refresh of a one of my two objects: my `Theme` object is directly refreshed without problem in the `Theme component` and the `topbar component` contrary to my `Category` which is only refreshed on the `Category component` and not directly in the `topbar component`. I need to go back to my homepage to refresh my `topbar component`.

[image: test]

Below my models implementation:

```
export class Theme {
  _id: string;
  name: string;
  description: string;
  iconCode: string;
  categories: Category[];
  createdAt: Date;
  updatedAt: Date;

export class Category {
  _id: string;
  name: string;
  description: string;
  createdAt: Date;
  updatedAt: Date;
```

My `CategoryStoreService`:

```
export class CategoryStoreService {

  private _categories: BehaviorSubject<Category[]> = new BehaviorSubject<Category[]>([]);
  private dataStore: {
    categories: Category[]
  };

  constructor(private categoryBackendService: CategoryBackendService) {
    this.dataStore = { categories: [] };
    this._categories = new BehaviorSubject<Category[]>([]);
  }

  get categories() {
    return this._categories.asObservable();
  }

  addThemeCategory(themeId: string, category: Category) {
    this.categoryBackendService.addThemeCategory(themeId, category).subscribe(
      res => {
        this.dataStore.categories.push(res);
        this._categories.next(Object.assign({}, this.dataStore).categories);
      },
      err => console.log('Error creating the category')
    );
  }
```

My `ThemeStoreService` :

```
export class ThemeStoreService {

  private _themes: BehaviorSubject<Theme[]> = new BehaviorSubject<Theme[]>([]);
  private dataStore: {
    themes: Theme[]
  };

  constructor(private themeBackendService: ThemeBackendService) {
    this.dataStore = { themes: [] };
    this._themes = new BehaviorSubject<Theme[]>([]);
  }

  get themes() {
    return this._themes.asObservable();
  }

  /**
   * Get the themes and their categories from the server and load it to the
   * data store
   */
  getThemes() {
    this.themeBackendService.getThemes().subscribe(
      res => {
        this.dataStore.themes = res;
        this._themes.next(Object.assign({}, this.dataStore).themes);
      },
      err => console.log("Error retrieving the themes")
    );
  }
```

I subscribed to my `ThemeStoreService`in the `app.component.ts` with the following code :

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  themes$: Observable<Theme[]>;

  constructor(private themeStoreService: ThemeStoreService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    // Subscribe to the themes
    this.themes$ = this.themeStoreService.themes;
    // Load all the themes
    this.themeStoreService.getThemes();
  }
```

And its template:

```
<app-topbar [themes]="themes$ | async"></app-topbar>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

And because I subscribed to the `Theme` which is linked to my `Category`by the field `categories`in the data model of the Theme, the view is not supposed to update automatically in my topbar?

The topbar is a dumb component receiving the `themes` via @Input() property and displaying the themes and categories with the followig code:

```
<li class="nav-item dropdown" *ngFor="let theme of themes">
    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
      <span [innerHTML]="theme.iconCode"></span>
      {{theme.name}}
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
      <li *ngFor="let category of theme.categories">
        <a class="dropdown-item" [routerLink]="['/threads']" [queryParams]="{ category: category._id }">
          {{category.name}}
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
```

And the .ts file

```
export class TopbarComponent {

  @Input() themes: Theme[];

}
```

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Trying to understand the issue here :
D you mean when you add a new category, its not added instantly? and that only on refresh it shows up?

Comment: Please, post your ThemeStoreService.

Comment: I updated my post with the ThemeStoreService. @GokulPrasad: The new category is added in its component but not in the topbar component.

Comment: You say that your TopBarComponent receives its values via @Input(). How do you trigger the event in your parent component? Please show the HTML-Code of your Parent-Component and the corresponding code in your parent's ts-file.

Comment: @DiabolicWords: I updated the post.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that your child component is declaring:

`@Input() themes: Theme[];`

And you parent component is passing an **async Observable stream**:

`<app-topbar [themes]="themes$ | async"></app-topbar>`

where `themes$` has is typed as `Observable`.

`[themes]="themes$ | async"` does not work in a custom input directive last I checked. You need to extract the data from the `Observable` **themes$** manually using a `Subscription`, and then pass the data:

```
import { ..., OnInit, OnDestroy } from ... //psuedo-code, add OnDestroy
import { ..., Subscription } from 'rxjs'; // psuedo-code, add Subscription

export class AppComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  themes: Theme[];
  themesSub: Subscription;

  constructor(private themeStoreService: ThemeStoreService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    // Subscribe to the themes
    this.themesSub = this.themeStoreService.themes.subscribe({ data => this.themes = data });
    // Load all the themes
    this.themeStoreService.getThemes();
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.themesSub.unsubscribe();
  }
```

don't forget to change the html: `<app-topbar [themes]="themes"></app-topbar>`

Comment: Unfortunately, I have the same behavior with these modifications. I am wondering if my problem is not directly in my services. Is there a way to do a "one to many" with the Observable Data Services? Because I have this relation between the Themes and the Categories.

Comment: @jocactus As long as your root module (your app.module.ts) is the one acting as the provider any component that attaches to the Observable data should have the same instance of that data. For BehaviorSubject services you should always import to root. Clarifying your imports and showing your _entire_ files may help, but my guess is that you're not providing the services correctly.

Comment: You will find a [gist](https://gist.github.com/jocactus/66d2a9456a9a880d3f7470f1a6280ed1) with an extract of my code. I imported with the @Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' }) tag and not directly in the root. Hope it will clarify.

Comment: @jocactus All that appears syntactically correct. You mentioned previously that the data is updating in the app.component, but not the topbar.component. How did you confirm this? Doing a console.log of both `themes` and `categories` in both the services, app component, as well as the topbar component in the subscription may help debug/confirm.

Comment: @jocactus Last ditch effort attempt to help ya: `this.themes$ = this.themeStoreService.themes();` <--- you should be calling a method (you want the returned Obs), but you're setting themes$ to be defined as a function.